# What does this warning mean in PHP , I occassionally get it on my site?

Tags: php, caching, directory, warnings, php-5.3

So I'm running a classified ads website and users upload images as well , but occasionally I get this warning here . I'd like to add that all the images get uploaded in just ONE upload folder now containing 4680 image files .. Could it be due to the fact that there are too many image files in that folder ?  What does the warning below mean ?  I'd like to fix this issue. It pops up sometimes , and when I refresh the page , it goes away ..

```
Warning: imagepng() [function.imagepng]: Unable to open '/home/content/72/9959172/html/thumb_cache/185x200__width__uploaded_files^classified_img^tractor61354.PNG' for writing: Stale NFS file handle in /home/content/72/9959172/html/al/includes/funcs_lib.inc.php on line 1168
```

Comment: well firstly, its a warning, so if your getting this on a production server i highly suggest turning of Warnings in your php.ini, secondly yes I would advise organising images into sub-directories, but i'm not sure this is why your getting the error.

Comment: @StevieNix, wow, has the music business gone so far south that you're into web design now? *sigh*

Comment: Sounds like a windows (WAMP) server issue.  Switch to open source!

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 Thanks for the feedback , I am using Godaddy for hosting , is there a way I can turn off warnings for my script ? since I cant control godaddy's PHP ini ?   what would that warning be ?

Comment: @SableFoste Godaddy uses linux

Comment: hmm, i actually hosted with GoDaddy once, and then quickly migrated to a new host.  I'm not sure it will work, but you can try `error_reporting(0); init_set('display_errors','0');` at the beginning of your application.

Comment: I don't know why GoDaddy would be using NFS mounts on a Linux server, seems like a stupid idea for a professional hosting provider.. lol, I'd honestly look at other hosts to be honest, amazon AWS, or rackspace or something..

Comment: ok , will do ... so Godaddy is bad for hosting ?

Comment: I generally think so yes, and by looking at this, it seems like a pretty rookie error in filesystem administration for a big hosting provider.. lol

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 so what is the difference in terms of importance between warnings and errors in PHP ? warnings will still let your site perform with no issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Just googled the error (like you probably should have done) and first result was this:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nfs-stale-file-handle-error-and-solution.html

> A filehandle becomes stale whenever the file or directory referenced by the handle is removed by another host, while your client still holds an active reference to the object. A typical example occurs when the current directory of a process, running on your client, is removed on the server (either by a process running on the server or on another client).

(From [Managing NFS and NIS](http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FManaging-NIS-2nd-Hal-Stern%2Fdp%2F1565925106%2Fsr%3D1-1%2Fqid%3D1160421456%3Fie%3DUTF8%26s%3Dbooks&tag=cyberciti-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325) via the website linked above)

I would probably suggest not using NFS mounts, and try to use Unix EXT3/4 mounts, as they are much more stable.

Comment: I was just writing the same answer providing the same link. I added the quote from the book cited on this site for the case that the link gets broken in the future.

Comment: @morten.c what to do when you use shared hosting like Godaddy ? how can I fix this issue ???

Comment: @StevieNix I fear there's not much you could do about it, since Godaddy propably won't change the way they're mounting home directories because you're getting php warnings. But what I'm curious about is that I'm not sure what is breaking the file handles. Because when I understand the filehandle stales corrrectly, there must be another client which deletes files. Maybe this is a cronjob running on that machine or you're accessing the files directly by FTP or something like that (Cleaned up the cache directory recently?). If you're site don't show any issues, maybe you just should go ahead.

Comment: @morten.c Thank you for taking the time to answer .. so that warning is the hosting not me right ?  What hosting service would you recommend me to use and how should I go about making sure that the next hosting doesn't give me the same warning ?  Rackspace maybe ?  I hear that godaddy hosting is horrible ... It is a classifieds ads website I'm hosting on there . I really wish I could show you the site by sending you a private email so you can maybe suggest me more .. would you mind ?  It's a nice classifieds for the continent of Europe getting hits already

Comment: @StevieNix Sorry but I'm not really into shared hosting services since I host everything I do on (virtual) private servers. If you have enough skills in server administration that would be a thought worth considered, especially if this isn't the only site you like to host.